# Forge AWS Laravel Install

Tags: laravel-5.1, amazon-ec2, forge, laravel-forge

Has anybody encountered any issues using forge with AWS for a laravel project?

I've recently followed instructions but I've encountered various errors too many to comment.

After opening a SSH connection to my AWS EC2 instance I've then run the command provided by Taylor on Forge but I get cannot find folder errors etc?

Answer (score 0):

I got a lot of problems with Forge + AWS.

Some of them were:

- You should specify correct snapshot for AWS instance - use ubuntu, not Amazon Linux.
- You should open SSH for whole world (or get Forge IP address)
- Other, a LOT of problems :)
  But in the End, I managed to install it.